# How can I turn the page's font color to green when a button is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

For example, this is my html code:

```
​<p style="color:blue">​I'm Blue</p>
<p id="p_red">I'm Red​</p>
<p>​I'm default, black</p>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Set color" />
```

css:

```
​#p_red{
    color: red;
}​
```

I'd like to turn the page's font color to green when the button is clicked:

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){
    document.body.style.color = "green";
}​;​
```

But it seems that only the default one(the black one) changed, the blue and red one doesn't work...
How could do this?

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/M5AQ4/

​

Comment: You should work with jquery, it will be easier to achieve what you want

Comment: jQuery isn't needed for this, just an understanding of style inheritance and how to remove, add, or change styles. It's worth noting that well-constructed markup also makes the job much easier. If you were exclusively using classes, you wouldn't have to worry about the brute-force power of the inline style. ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than setting the colour directly, assign a style to the body as follows:

```
document.body.className += " green";
```

Where the "green" style is in your stylesheet as follows:

```
#p_red{
    color: red;
}
body.green, .green p {
    color: green !important;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/M5AQ4/5/

The `body.green, .green p` selector in the stylesheet will apply the specified colour to the body only when it has the "green" class, and to any p elements that are descendents of an element that has the "green" class - the `!important` flag means it will override other styles that might otherwise have taken precendence under normal cascade rules. You can change the second selector to `.green *` to apply it to all element types that are descendts of "green".

Comment: This seems like a lot more effort than is necessary. no?

Comment: @DvideBy0 - if you count the stylesheet change as one line (given you could put it all on one line) it is a total of two lines of code, which doesn't seem like much effort to me (noting that the OP already had the `#p_red` bit in their stylesheet). If you know a way to do it in less than two lines _without including an external library_ let me know...

Answer (score 4):

You are setting the BODY color which will be inherited by its children UNLESS they have their own colors set. I suggest that you restructure your solution, e.g. by adding a "green" CSS class to BODY (`document.body.className = "green";`) and having your stylesheet like this:

```
body.green, body.green * {
  color: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could loop everything with javascript.

```
var elms = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); 
for(var x in elms) 
{
    elms[x].style.color = 'green'; 
}
```

Comment: If you want only certain items to be green you could put some logic in the loop

Answer (score 1):

and if you do plan on using jQuery, simple solution:

```
$("p").each(function (i) {
    this.style.color = "green";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
$('*').css({"color":"green"});
```

I have not tested this myself but seems logical.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
$("*").css("color", "green");
```

Instead of

```
document.body.style.color = "green";
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5bNP/)

Comment: Note that the question isn't tagged with "jQuery". (And that this solution even turns button text green.)